# JSON jQuery PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I don't understand one thing. If I want to get JSON data (key-value-pairs) from PHP to jQuery using Ajax, which of the following ones should I use?

- `$.get`
- `$.post`
- `$.getJSON`

Do I need to use `getJSON` if I want to use `json_encode` in a PHP file? But what if I want to send with post (there is no `postJSON`)?

And one more thing:

In a PHP file I wrote:

```
<?php
    if($_GET['value'] == "value")
    {
        $array['firstname'] = 'Johnny';
        $jsonstring=json_encode($array);
        return $jsonstring;
    }
?>
```

In the jQuery file:

```
  $.getJSON("php.php", {value: "value"}, function(data){
      alert(data.firstname);
  });
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies with the line in PHP:

```
return $jsonstring;
```

You should echo it instead:

```
echo $jsonstring;
```

As for which jQuery method to use, I suggest `$.getJSON()` if you can return a pure json string. It really depends on how you use it.

When using `$.getJSON()`, your server file should return a JSON string. Thus echoing the string returned by `json_encode()` would be appropriate for the `$.getJSON()` method to take in the response.

Comment: but in tutorials i have seen they are using return. and it seemed to work..?

Comment: what if i send multiple json_encode() values with echo in a php? the last one will be the one jquery retrieves?

Comment: That would depend on the browser. It might use that last one, or the first one, or just error out and use nothing. Better to wrap it all into a `json_encode` if you need to do that:   `json_encode(array(json_encode($data1), json_encode($data2)));`

Comment: the best way is still to consolidate all data into one single array, parse it through json_encode, and echo it.

Comment: just to remind you that using GET in AJAX is much efficient. try googling on this. I read one article which touches on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.ajax`, this allows you to do both `get` and `post`.

Comment: You could also just use `$.get` or `$.post` ;-]

Answer (score 0):

I always use $.ajax.

```
$.ajax({
     url: "script.php",
     type: "POST",
     data: { name : "John Doe" },
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(msg){
        alert(msg);
     }
});
```

in PHP:

```
$name = $_POST['name']
echo $name
```

this will alert "John Doe"

also, if it's not working, use firebug to see values being passed around.

Comment: is post much better than get? because i send password values to the php, so post is better for security reason?

Comment: and why dont they do a $.postJSON?

Comment: You could just as well use `$.post(url, data, callback, 'json')`. No reason to type out all that when they have wrapped it into a nice shortcut function for you. Not unless you plan to do something out of the ordinary.

Comment: @ fayer - POST or GET is up to you. I don't know why they don't have $.postJSON

@ Atli: $.POST doesn't have a 'success', 'error' and 'complete' callback.